Mac Catalyst DocumentGroup shows blank view when "Optimize for Mac" is enabled
I'm developing a document-based SwiftUI app using Mac Catalyst with DocumentGroup. When creating a new document or opening an existing one, the view appears completely blank, but only when "Optimize for Mac" is enabled in the target settings. The view displays correctly when using "Scaled to Match iPad" instead.
Environment
Xcode 16.1
macOS 15.1
SwiftUI with Mac Catalyst
Document-based app using DocumentGroup
Code
struct DocumentGroupTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: WritingAppDocument()) { file in
            TestView() // Blank when "Optimize for Mac" is enabled
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

Expected Behavior
The TestView should display its content ("Hello, World!" text) when the document is opened or created
The view should work correctly regardless of the Mac Catalyst optimization settings
Actual Behavior
When "Optimize for Mac" is enabled: The view appears completely blank
When "Scaled to Match iPad" is enabled: The view works as expected
What I've Tried
Confirmed the issue only occurs with "Optimize for Mac" setting
Verified the basic view works in iPad mode
Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to fix the blank view while keeping "Optimize for Mac" enabled?

Why use Mac Catalyst for a SwiftUI app? Why not setup your SwiftUI project with a native Mac build?

Our primary app is an iOS app, and we converted that easily as a catalyst, and it worked flawlessly so far. This is the only issue we are encountering (+ that mouse support is limited).
Creating a completely new one with shared code would require a lot of work. 90% of our users are coming from iOS.
